# Pattern for synchronising multipart asynchronous calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I'm trying to find a pattern to use when synchronising multipart asynchronous operations. Lets say the OS offers a service which can be started/stopped. Take the following example:

1. Start is called. Ask the daemon to start.
2. The daemon responds successfully. Do some other operation, such as setting necessary state of operation.
3. The daemon responds, we are done.

What I want is to prevent activities from overlapping. Say that while 1. is processing a stop request (or another start) is issued. That request must hold until 3. completes.

I know about [dispatches queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) and I'm actually using them, but they prevent each **step** from overlapping, not the entire operation. I tried using locks but I get an instant log from iOS telling me that a dead lock occurred (I don't release the lock until 3. finishes). I also tried some ad-hoc approaches but they have been revealing hard to use. My last attempt:

```
@interface HYPAtomizer : NSObject

// Indicates that the operation is running. A start request was successful    
@property (readonly) BOOL isRunning;

// Whether the operation/daemon should be running
@property (readonly) BOOL isRunningRequested;

// Whether we are currently processing a request
@property (readonly) BOOL isProcessing;

// Whether an error occurred
@property (readonly) NSError * error;

- (instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
+ (instancetype)atomizer;

// These methods return YES if I should proceed with the request, meaning that it's not overlapping
- (BOOL)startIfPossible;
- (BOOL)stopIfPossible;

// Call these by the time a request finishes. They will say whether to revert the process, meaning that a request happened during processing that requires the state to turn back (such as a stop request being issued during a start process)
- (BOOL)revertStartIfNeeded:(NSError *)error;
- (BOOL)revertStopIfNeeded:(NSError *)error;

// A spontaneous stoppage occurred, such as the daemon stopping by itself
- (void)notifyStoppage:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

I then call these methods at key points, but it's been proving hard to find those key points. Is there a standard method?

Edit for clarification purposes:

Steps on any given activity don't repeat, but they are not mandatory either. As such, a start operation can execute 1, 2, and 3, but it could also stop at 2 if that step detects an error and 3 never gets executed. Steps don't repeat, so 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3 is not possible. These situations are possible:

```
[lock] 1, 2 - fail [unlock]
[lock] 1, 2, 3 - success [unlock]
```

If in the meanwhile (while I'm waiting for the daemon) **any** other operation is attempt, be it either start or stop, it shouldn't execute, but instead update a flag indicating what the current state should be. Lets say that `(start)` is a start request and `(stop)` the opposite activity. The following would happen:

```
(start) [lock] 1, 2, 3 [unlocked] (stop) [lock] 1, 2 [unlock]
(start) [lock] 1, 2, (stop), 3 [unlock] [lock] 1, 2 [unlock]
```

The `(stop)` request in the last example was called by a foreign source, it's not part of the start process. As you can see by the time that start finishes I want it to stop, because it was requested in the meanwhile. Finally, if more actions overlap:

```
(start) [lock] 1, (stop), 2, (start), 3 [unlock] - nothing happens
```

In this case nothing happens because by the time the process is finishes it's already in the last requested state (start).

Edit: BTW, I'm just thinking of implementing a simple lock mechanism like described.

Comment: Have you looked into using `NSOperation` and dependencies? Here is a great article to get going on it. You may have to subclass each of your 3 steps as separate `NSOperations` and then add the dependency amongst them. http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

Comment: Hm. Close, but not quite. I seem to have the same issue with this as I do with GCD. When an activity finishes the next one is fetched but this must not happen. What motivates this is the fact that I have to wait for the daemon to respond until I close the activity. Would you know how to apply `NSOperation` on a situation like this?

Comment: It isn't clear what is your atomic operation? Should 1,2 and 3 complete before another sequence of 1,2 and 3 is permitted?  Can a single requester actually request operation 1,2,2,2...3?  What should happen to the other requester when they request 1 while 3 is already happening? Should the request fail, or block, or queue without blocking? Can another requester request 2 if someone else has already started the daemon? Is it actually the specific overlap of 1 and 3 that is the issue?

Comment: Please see my edit! Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Promises pattern was designed for situations like this. I found PromiseKit to be a good implementation on iOS. Chaining is the feature that you're looking for.

[PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org)

[Chaining](http://promisekit.org/chaining/)

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting, but doesn't this have the same issues I described? It just seems to haver better syntax

Comment: The chained promise doesn't execute until the previous promise is fulfilled and each promise isn't fulfilled until your asynchronous operation completes. See the tutorial on sealing your own promises to see how to create your promise. http://promisekit.org/sealing-your-own-promises/

Comment: The idea is to call resolve in the promise creation block when your asynchronous operation is complete. Then the next chained promise can begin execution.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about NSOperationQueue class? I guess that's exactly the thing you're looking for. You can define priorities, dependencies, cancel individual operations etc very easily. Nice and neat API. Just check the docs (sorry for not posting direct link).

Comment: that has already been suggested in the comments, but as I said it doesn't help because it doesn't wait for the asynchronous operations to finish.

Comment: Yes, it does - maybe you missed the line where I wrote "you can define ... dependencies"?

Comment: I don't think we are talking about the same thing. Dependencies define the order of the operations in the queue. That's a given. What I **can't** have is an operation trigger as soon as previous one finishes, because I need to wait for a response of an asynchronous operation. Say you have blocks A and B. When A finishes, B must wait for a response from a daemon to run. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Well, sorry for not providing any sample code right now, I'm almost sleeping, but that's exactly what I'm used to do with it. Let's say you have operations A and B, but operation B depends on A and should be fired when it finishes. Then you can create 2 NSOperation instances, tell B operation it depends on A, put it to the NSOperationsQueue and that's it. This article nicely explains how it works: http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/. Check "dependencies" section.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an completionBlock()  to your NSOperations, which you could utilize along with a singleton properties on a manager class to check your status and etc.

Set up a startOperation, and for startOperation.completionBlock, have something like startOperation.completionBlock = ^{[[DaemonManager defaultManager] checkIfStopRequestedAndHandle];};.

With completionBlock, addDependency, and isCancelled and isFinished, you should have enough tools to tailor the execution step/dependency as you see fit